# iOS: More tab crashes on my subclassed UITabBarController on iOS 7.1

Tags: ios7, uitabbarcontroller

I simply updated to iOS 7.1 and I get an unrecognized selection error for a function called "_layoutCells".

I have a simple subclass of UITabBarController.

Comment: Same issue here. I'm not able to find the bug. Is it on our side or on Apples?

Comment: I have sumbitted a Bug Report about this issue with Apple. Problem ID 16299264.

Answer (score 4):

Note that this is a hack to avoid a bad crash until a better solution or explanation is found.  I though I should share it.

Simply add the following method to your UITabBarController subclass implementation:

```
- (void) _layoutCells
{
    // HACK ALERT: on iOS 7.1, this method will be called from deep within the bowels of iOS.  The problem is that
    // the method is not implemented and it results in an unrecognized selected crash. So we implement it...
    //
    // What could go wrong?
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea – even as a workaround solution. The only case where it should be used is in development (for testing the other views that can't be accessed because of this bug). But Apps should not be published with this workaround as this method overrides the behavior of `_layoutCells` which could brake the expected behavior of iOS.

In my opinion it's better to just let Apple fix it. I have posted a bug report about this: Problem ID 16299264.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same bug. My problem is that I'm providing my custom datasource and delegate for more tab's tableview. This method is called with delegate class. DO share when apple relies.

Comment: Same issue here. I'm going to submit today with the workaround hack. I'll let everyone know if I get rejected.

Comment: @Dschee: I agree, but our app was crashing, we needed a workaround and fast.

I also reported the issue, but can't find the problem id.  Thanks for the new report!

Note: our app was approved and released.

Comment: All, on my bug report, I was asked for crash logs, which I provided.  Stay tuned!

Comment: I put my own answer based off of yours. My case might be different, but I don't just stop the call to _layoutCells

Comment: Thanks Michael.  Still no answer from Apple.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to GenesisST for giving his answer, but I know methods are called for a reason. And usually layoutCells will call layout for all subviews. While I rather wait for an answer from Apple, I like other people need to submit my app within a given timeline.

In my case, I was getting this error due to some hacks. I had replaced the UIMoreNavigationController delegate, which is an undocumented class by Apple, so I could expect errors. I am doing this hack to extend the More tab's functionality, and this error only occurs when I change the moreNavigationController tableView's delegate.

So I store their delegate, change it, then call _layoutCells to their delegate when iOS calls it on my class.

```
- (void)_layoutCells
{
   if([self.moreTableViewDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(_layoutCells)]){
      [self.moreTableViewDelegate performSelector:@selector(_layoutCells)];
   }
}
```

I don't know if this apply's to anyone here, but just in case someone else comes to SO with my edge case.

Comment: Thanks Michael!  I too was replacing the more nav controller delegate.  I had tried to check if the superclass did implement _layoutCells, but it didn't, because it was the delegate it was trying to call!

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue in my app where I have provided custom delegate/datasource to the more tableview controller. I haven't figured out why, but it seems that _layoutCells method is invoked on the more tableview controller.
I fixed it, adding this method:

```
-(NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
    // self.viewController is my tabBarController
    UINavigationController* moreNavigationController = self.viewController.moreNavigationController; 

    // Retrieve the more list controller (it is the first in the hierarchy)
    id moreListController = moreNavigationController.viewControllers.firstObject;

    Class moreTableViewClass = [moreListController class];
    if (moreTableViewClass) {
        return [moreTableViewClass instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:aSelector];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

I've done various test and it seems a reliable workaround. But if you'll find better solution... share it!

Comment: For me: your method returns a selector for _layoutCells, which is the same things causes the problem and then still causes "unrecognized selector".