# iOS 7: Exception "layoutCell / unrecognized selector" when clicking on the "More" button of TabBar

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm using a UITAbBarViewController and I want to customize the "More" view so I've used this code:

```
`if (this.MoreNavigationController != null) 
{
    UITableView tableView = (UITableView)this.MoreNavigationController.TopViewController.View;
    tableView.BackgroundView = null;
    tableView.TableFooterView = new UIView (new CGRect ());

    var ds = new MoreTableDataSource (viewControllers.Skip(4).ToArray());

    tableView.Source = ds;
}`
```

My class MoreTableDataSource is this one:

```
`public class MoreTableDataSource : UITableViewSource
{
        UIViewController[] tableItems;
        protected string cellIdentifier = "TableCell";

        public Action<UIViewController, int> SelectRow { get; set; }

        public MoreTableDataSource (UIViewController[] items)
        {
            this.tableItems = items;

            SelectRow = null;
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return tableItems.Length;
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);
            if (cell == null)
            {
                cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier);
                cell.TextLabel.Text = tableItems[indexPath.Row].Title;
                cell.ImageView.Image = tableItems [indexPath.Row].TabBarItem.Image;
                cell.AccessoryView = ColoredDisclosureIndicator.AccessoryWithColor(TouchApplication.SodexoColor);
            }

            return cell;
        }
    }`
```

This code works perfectly on iOS 8 but throw the following exception on iOS 7:

> Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name:
>   NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[MyApp_Views_MoreTableDataSource
>   _layoutCells]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7bf09fa0

I've tried to search on Google but I've found anything that could help me.

Is there someone that could have an idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: It is likely happening in another place of the code, but it is hard to tell with just this snippet.

Comment: Miguel, Thanks for your answer. The problem really occured as soon as I set the source of the TableView (with tableView.Source = ds;). If i removed this line, the app worked fine (no more crashes on iOS 7).

This looks like the same bug as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309289/ios-more-tab-crashes-on-my-subclassed-uitabbarcontroller-on-ios-7-1

I've ended by managing the "More" table myself by adding/using a custom UITableView but I'm interesting to know why this could to happen :)

Thanks !